# what regex could match this?

Tags: python, regex

I have the following string:

```
string='script=dqweqweqwe qewq ewqewqewe$int_qwe$\r\n\r\nintqewwqe wqe thisCanChange=5711'
```

I can't figure how to match `'dqweqweqwe qewq ewqewqewe$int_qwe$\r\n\r\nintqewwqe wqe'`.

I tried this:

```
regex=r'script=(.*?) .*?='
```

But obviously it's only matching `'dqweqweqwe'`

Could you please advise me ?

Comment: I'm assuming this is python?

Comment: Yes it is python

Comment: What about [`(?<=script=)[^=]*(?!\S)`](https://regex101.com/r/OsIo64/2)?

Comment: awesome, many thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/OsIo64/2)

```
(?<=script=)[^=]*(?!\S)
```

- `(?<=script=)` Positive loobehind ensuring what precedes is `script=`
- `[^=]*` Match any character except `=` any number of times
- `(?!\S)` Negative lookahead ensuring what follows is not any character except whitespace. What this means is that it ensures either whitespace exists as the following character, or that there is no character (end of the string).

Answer (score 0):

Use a greedy quantifier so that you match up to the last space rather than the first one.

```
regex=r'script=(.*) '
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/fO99yl/1)

Comment: Thanks, it's working, though i'll use the regex from @ctwheels above as it is more scalable. (anticipating the fact that I may have additional stuff at the end of my string in the future)